# Random network request failed error when fetching local path uri with XMLHttpRequest on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, xmlhttprequest

Recently I am facing a weird problem on IOS with React Native when using XMLHttpRequest to convert path uri to Blob. It gives a random network request error. So sometimes it works and sometimes not on the same network. The error only happens on physical IOS devices (Android works fine) and not on the IOS emulator on my computer.

I am using React Native: 0.61.5 and iOS 13. The code worked on IOS 12 devices.

Code:

```
export function urlToBlob(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(new Error('uriToBlob failed'));
    };
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

I also tried react native fetch which gives the same problems.

Info.pl list

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I don't know if it is possible, but a solution might be to work around fetch and convert the path uri to blob without a http request.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging and reading a lot of docs I finally got the solution. I noticed that the uri refering to the image (produced by taking a photo or opening a file) was not correct anymore. When using that uri to generate a blob it gives an error. Because the error handling of XMLHttpReques is very poor it only gave me a network request failed error. So what i did to solve the error is to generate a blob from the uri right after the uri was generated. I think the cause of the error is that perhaps a higher version of IOS 12/13 handles the cache where the uri refers to different then previous versions.